# CLion only Debug configuration

Tags: c++, configuration, cmake, clion

I've updated CLion to the latest version (2016.3.2).

But when I open my project, I can compile only in one configuraion *debug*
all the rest are missing.

[image]

On the previous version I could choose between:

- Debug
- Release
- MinSizeRelease
- RelWithDebInfo

Nothing was changed but the version upgrade of Clion.

Comment: https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2016/10/clion-2016-3-eap-cmake-overload-resolution/  "One configuration at a time"  I still use the previous version as I prefer it.  They really changed the cmake interface and I don't care for it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

CMake workflow indeed changed significantly in CLion 2016.3: the decision to leave only a single configuration was a performance-related trade-off back then.

However, the ability to use multiple configuration was re-implemented and improved [in 2016.3.2](https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2016/12/clion-2016-3-2-eap/#cmake_configurations):

> Go to *Settings/Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | CMake* and create any number of CMake configurations from scratch, or copy existing ones (with all the settings pre-filled). When done, additional resolve context will be available in the bottom right-hand switcher in the editor.
>
> [image: CMake configurations in CLion 2016.3.2]